# "Guess the number" game

Tags: logical-deduction, meta-knowledge

two logicians decided to play a lovely well-known game , number-guessing from the least significant informations , the juror proposed to create the challenge :

the juror told the logicians two numbers secretly , unbeknownst to eachother , all they know , is that the product of eachother's number is a **number divisible by 2 , and between 2 and 10.**

juror said that , no action is permitted , no gestures , no word , except when they know numbers , they are permitted to announce it!

> - A suspensious silence was been hovering arround the place , no word! everyone was staring at the other wierdly .

After this few minutes silence both jumped suddenly and declared : We know these numbers!

**Question**: What are these numbers ?

Comment: Can both logicians be given the same number and are the numbers integers?

Comment: the numbers are integers 1 isnt included , 10 is included . DOT.

Comment: I am just double checking... the product is between 2 and 10?  their numbers are integers?

Comment: yes........this is my easiest logic puzzle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that both of their numbers (a,b) are integers.  Neither can be 0 and if either are negative, they know the other has a negative number so it is trivial to reduce it to the same problem.

Both players know that all possible pairs contain at least a 1 or a 2.  If either player has a 10, 8, 6, 5, or 3, then they immediately know to combine it with the 1 or 2 to find the 1 possible product within that range.  As no one immediately finds the solution, neither player has these numbers.

The only numbers a player may have, therefore, is 1, 2, or 4.  It has been revealed since I starting writing the answer that neither player can have a 1.  The possible pairs are, therefore: (2,2) and (2,4).

> If either player had a 4, they would realise that the other has a 2 and say the result.  This means that they both know it is (2,2).

Comment: this answer was first .

Comment: @Agawa001 Just remember that "first" doesn't always correspond to "best". It's a good habit to leave a question open for a while, even if a correct answer has been posted, unless you're sure that no better answer could be posted. 
Btw, nice answer kaine!

Comment: do you think i would choose it if it wasnt corrent ?

Answer (score 3):

Lets assume that we are one of the logicians and get a number, how much can you reason out from that number?

Numbers 6+ are impossible because the minimum is two and the product can't be higher than 10. 
Number 5: The other must have two, otherwise the product would not be divisible by 2.
Number 4: The other must have two.
Number 3: The other must have two, otherwise the end product is not divisible by two.
Number 2: The other must have 2 or 4.

The only combination that carries uncertainty for both parties is if both have the number 2, hence this is the number that both logicians had.

Answer (score 1):

So the product of the two numbers lies between 2 and 10 and has to be divisible by two 2. The following are the possible pairs:

1. 10:(2,5)
2. 8:(2,4)
3. 6:(2,3)
4. 4:(2,2)
5. 2:(2,1)

In cases **1,2,3 and 5**, the logician with the number other than 2 can blurt out his number and correctly guess that the other logician has the number two.

But in case **4**, since both of them fall silent as either one has the value two. Therefore, both the logicians know they have the same number, i.e., 2.